# MVC3 Razor view engine, error when creating a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm evaluating MVC 3 and Razor.  All was going well until I tried right clicking on Views\Shared and Add..View... I check the 'Create a partial' checkbox, strongly typed view, choose an entity, Razor, Empty... When I press OK, I get a huge error. Template Processing resulted in 1 Errors.  The following exception was thrown: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Domain, Version-1.0.0.0... Trying this on a coworkers machine gave me no problems.  We have the same version of MVC 3 installed. Any ideas why her's works just fine but I am getting this error? I have tried running as Administrator as well.  Still no luck. Oddly if I uncheck strongly typed view, the partial view is created without a problem.  Does anyone know how I can remedy this?

Thanks For any tips or help,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: Could you post the entire error? Do you have any visual studio extensions that might be interfering with the project?

Comment: Would be helpful to hear any resolutions and/or followup on this. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to this and have the same issue. A workaround seems to be to remove the reference, create the partial view and than add the reference again. So it seems to be something inside this reference (corrupt).